# Error: [ngModel:numfmt] when parsing a value in angular with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I need to set a value to an input type='number' with ng-model but despite parsing my scope variable to an Integer in my controller, my console throwing me an error message: Error: [ngModel:numfmt]

```
//controller    
$scope.theGrace =  parseInt($scope.customer.Grace);

//jade file
input.form-control(type='number' name='Grace' id='Grace' ng-model='theGrace')
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `$scope.theGrace` became a number? If `$scope.customer.Grace` was `undefined` or something maybe it didnt

Comment: Try `$scope.theGrace+=0`